# Console calculation speed?

Tags: c++, console-application

How to increase the Console calculation speed in c++ ?
im working in codeblocks . Is there any method to change the console speed so that it could calculate the things faster.

Comment: what are examples of the slow parts? Can you give us code examples or at least algorithms?

Comment: for example it is a program which finds the 10001 PRime no for this it has to do so much calculations.

Answer (score 4):

The console window does not run at a different "speed" from other programs running on your computer. It is not an emulator. It's just a window that displays the output from text-only applications. Those text-only applications run at full speed, just like any other application.

If your calculations are too slow, then you either need to upgrade your computer hardware and/or redesign the algorithms used in your code.

> for example it is a program which finds the 10001 PRime no for this it has to do so much calculations.

Yes, finding the first 10001 prime numbers is going to be a computationally-expensive operation. The speed is not a limitation of the console window, it's a limitation of your computer hardware (assuming that your algorithm is optimized to the extent possible).

You can test this by creating a *non-console* application (e.g., a standard Windows application that runs in its own window), running the exact same code, and printing the output with a MessageBox or writing it into a file. You'll see that that program finds the numbers at the same speed as your console app, demonstrating that it is not the console part that is slowing it down.

Comment: i hve a i3 but the console uses maximum 500k memry . does this effects its calculation speed?

Comment: @user How do you know that it uses a maximum of 500k memory? I'm pretty sure that's impossible, there are very few modern applications that can run in only 500k, even if they are text only.

Comment: i checked in the task manager. im using codeblocks . its exe takes only so much amount of memry , i have also tried by incressing priority level by nothing happnd. and you are right it is only txt base

Comment: @user Task Manager does not give the *maximum* amount of memory that an application can consume, it gives only the memory that it is *currently* consuming (or the maximum that it has ever consumed while it's been running). Task Manager is not giving you an upper limit on consumption because there isn't one. That's limited only by the available resources on your system. But more generally, Task Manager is not an acceptable memory profiler. If you don't have a really good understanding of what it's telling you (and that info is rarely useful to profiling), you'll often draw the wrong conclusion.

Comment: Moreover, increasing the priority won't make a process run any faster. All it does is ensure that it will get more processor time, *relative to other processes*. If your machine isn't doing anything else in the background, then your application (whether in a console window or another type of window) is getting the full attention of the computer. Windows already applies a slight optimization to speed up foreground applications.

Comment: Now question is that what should i do to incress its speed?

Comment: No idea, I'm too far away from your screen to see the code you've written. Perhaps ask a different question and include the code this time?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes printing unnecessary output to the console does slow things down.  If that's the case, try redirecting the output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You may check parallel programming methods. You can use API's such as OpenMP and you can speed up your calculations. Also avoid using too much prints on console.